# how to set cronjob for 2 days?

Tags: cron

We would like to use a cronjob to create a database backup.

The backup should occur ones every two days. Can the following cron-entry be used?

```
0 0 2 * * * backup-command
```

If this is wrong please tell me the correct command for setting the cron for 2 days.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

From [here](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html):

> Cron also supports 'step' values.
>
> A value of `*/2` in the dom field would
>   mean the command runs every two days
>   and likewise, `*/5` in the hours field
>   would mean the command runs every  5
>   hours. e.g.
>
> ```
> * 12 10-16/2 * * root backup.sh
> ```
>
> is the same as:
>
> ```
> * 12 10,12,14,16 * * root backup.sh
> ```

So I think you want `0 0 */2 * *`.

What you've got (`0 0 2 * *`) will run the command on the 2nd of the month at midnight, every month.

p.s. You seem to have an extra asterisk in your answer. The format should be:

```
minute hour dom month dow user cmd
```

So your extra asterisk would be in the `user` field. Is that intended?

Comment: Some fabled implementations also contain a field for seconds although I've never seen one in the wild.

Comment: `*/2` is clear, but what is `10-16/2` what does that mean?

Answer (score 10):

*Disclaimer: this is a copy of my `deleted` answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48503910/schedule-cron-job-every-2-days/48522066#48522066). I do believe this question is more **canonical**, and my answer fits better here.*

There are two ways this question can be interpreted.

- I would like to schedule a cron job every second day of the month.
- I would like to schedule a cron job every two days.

These are two completely different cases because of the number of days there are in a month.

### I would like to schedule a cronjob every second day of the month.

For this we use the combination of defining a range and a step value:

> **`man 5 crontab`:** Step values can be used in conjunction with ranges.  Following a range with `/<number>` specifies skips of the
>   number's value through the range.  For example, `0-23/2` can be used
>   in the 'hours' field to specify command execution for every other hour
>   (the alternative in the V7 standard is
>   `0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22`).  Step values are also permitted
>   after an asterisk, so if specifying a job to be run every two hours,
>   you can use `*/2`.

See the following examples:

```
# Example of job definition:
# .-------------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .----------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .-------------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |      .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |      |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
# |  |  |      |  |
# *  *  *      *  *   command to be executed
  0  0  */2    *  *   command1
  0  0  2-31/2 *  *   command2
  *  *  */2    *  *   command3
```

- `command1` will be executed at 00:00 on every odd-numbered day (default range with step 2, i.e. 1,3,5,7,...,31)
- `command2` will be executed at 00:00 on every even-numbered day (i.e. 2,4,6,8,...,30)
- `command3` is an often made mistake. This will run on every minute of every odd-numbered day.

**Note:** It should be understood that in this approach `command1` will run on both January 31st and February 1st (2 consecutive days)

**Note:** It should be understood that in this approach `command2` will skip both January 31st and February 1st and will run only 3 days later.

### I would like to schedule a cronjob every second day (starting from day X)

Here it gets more interesting. The notes above already demonstrated the problem with months having an odd number of days.

The quick way to think would be to evaluate the day of the year:

```
% date -d "2018-01-31" '+%j'
031
% date -d "2018-02-01" '+%j'
032
```

and you could easily investigate if it is an odd or even number. However, When doing this, you have again a problem on December 31st and January 1st in a common year (365 days; leap years have 366 days). This can be resolved when you have a continuous counter from a given day. Enter UNIX time stamp, the total seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`.

```
% date -d "2018-12-31" '+%s %j'                                                                                                                                                                                                               
1546214400 365
% date -d "2019-01-01" '+%s %j' 
1546300800 001
% date -d "2019-12-31" '+%s %j'                                                                                                                                                                                                               
1577750400 365
% date -d "2020-01-01" '+%s %j'                                                                                                                                                                                                               
1577836800 001
```

For a cronjob to run `command4` only every second day at `00:00` and `command5` every third day at `00:00` starting from "2018-03-14", the crontab would look like this:

```
# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  *   command to be executed
  0  0  *  *  *   daytestcmd 2 && command4
  0  0  *  *  *   daytestcmd 3 20180314 && command5
```

with `daytestcmd` defined as

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# get start time in seconds
start=$(date -d "${2:-@0}" '+%s')
# get current time in seconds
now=$(date '+%s')
# get the amount of days (86400 seconds per day)
days=$(( (now-start) /86400 ))
# set the modulo
modulo=$1
# do the test
(( days >= 0 )) && (( days % modulo == 0))
```

**Remark:** UNIX time is given in UTC. If your cron runs in a different time-zone which is influenced by daylight saving time, it is advisable not to run the command between 2 and 3 o'clock. This could skip the command or run the command twice (depending if the time jumps forward or backwards)

**Remark:** UNIX time is not influenced by leap seconds

Comment: Shouldn't it be `daytestcmd 2` and `daytestcmd 3`? Shell functions and scripts don't take their arguments in parentheses.

Comment: Another suggestion (mostly cosmetic, though): in `daytestcmd`, you could use just `(( days % modulo == 0 ))` instead of `[[ $(( days % modulo )) == 0 ]]`.

Comment: @BenjaminW Updated

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the `crontab -e` command, try this time pattern:

```
0 1 */2 * * command_to_execute
```

Or, you can try [SetCronJob](http://www.setcronjob.com) for a web based solution. You can easily create cron jobs every 2 days with the second creating row.

Comment: [SetCronJob](https://www.setcronjob.com) is not showing me the crontab format which is easy to use manually in our local system. How can I found that?