# @Scheduled Job for 10 days using Spring Java[close]

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I need to create a scheduled job that will occur after **interval** of each **10** days. But i am not sure what would be the written in the parameter of **@Scheduled** annotation of Spring. Can anyone define the **cron expression** for this job if i am using cron as an parameter in @Scheduled annotation or ***fixedDelay*** would be an better choice than ***cron***?

Comment: It looks like exact duplicate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382634/how-to-set-cronjob-for-2-days

Comment: Are the step values clever enough to handle months with 31 days and a leap year with 29 days in Feb. My understanding is that it would only fire on the 10th, 20th & 30th (if there is one) if the month value was */10. I think therefore the fixedDelay maybe a better option.

Comment: @mrswadge - Thanks for your answer. I got the solution to use fixedDelay by passing the total no of ms equivalent to 10 days to it.