# How to use the Linux Crontab to execute two tasks on alternative days?

Tags: linux, cron

I want to do this:

Execute Task A today 6:00am, and then every two days after that.

Execute Task B tomorrow 6:00am, and every two days after that.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382634/how-to-set-cronjob-for-2-days

Answer (score 0):

The normal solution for having a `cron` job execute every two days would be using `*/2` in the days field, but that doesn't support alternating days.

You'd probably have to make a list of days:

```
0 6 */2 * * #Job to execute every even numbered day
0 6 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31 * * #Job to execute every odd numbered day
```

Note that this won't be perfect on months that end with an odd number of days. Since it will end up executing the second job twice in a row, on the 31st and the 1st.

It's probably worth looking at `man crontab` on your system as well. Some `crons` support more complex forms of scheduling, such as dependencies (wait until this job finishes, then wait another X hours and run this other job) which could be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `date %s` to determine if it is an "odd" day or "even" day in a running calendar free of manmade boundaries of years and months. For example:

```
$ [ $(( `date +%s` / 86400 % 2 )) -eq 0 ] && echo A || echo B
```

And drive Task A or Task B thus.