# Schedule cron job every 2 days

Tags: linux, cron

As we already know that the pattern `* */2 * * *` executes the task for every 2 hour, similary  can `* * */2 * *` execute the task for every 2 day (once in 2 days). If yes, at what time the task will be executed?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Note that `* */2 * * *` runs the task once every minute of every 2. hour (it does not run once every 2 hours, if you wanted it to run once every 2 hours, on the hour, use `0 */2 * * *`

Comment: @jww Then how https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382634/how-to-set-cronjob-for-2-days got 28 upvotes?

Comment: @Prem - It is a common trap. That QA is from 2009. The site rules were different back then. The rules in effect now have been existed since 2012 or so.

Comment: @jww Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @Prem do you mean "every second day of the month" or "every second day"

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of dozen of posts about this topic, of which [this exhaustive one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382634/how-to-set-cronjob-for-2-days).

`0 0 2 * *` : every 2 days at midnight, every month.
`0 0 */2 * *` : 2nd of the month at midnight, every month.

Comment: Don't just copy someone's else's answer. Instead, flag the question as a duplicate.

Comment: @columbia : I did not copy anything. Obviously it is a duplicate. So what, not valid enough to downgrade a correct answer and play the teacher. Not fair and no value added vs. answering appropriately to a question.

Comment: It is the other way around. */2 means every two time units.