# How can I set crontab for run daily after specified date?

Tags: shell, cron

I didn't get any idea of running the program daily after the specified date to idefinitely using crontab.

I tried below command but it's not working.

```
python3 $(date=$(date +%Y%m%d); if [ $date -gt 20180315 ]; then echo '--version'; else echo '/home/raman/Desktop/testp.py '; fi)
```

Where
 20180315 = this is specified date after I have to run the program.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48547339/8344060

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to convert the dates into seconds. Also it's better to make a bash script(say runPyAfterDate.sh) with the code below and save it in a suitable directory(I suggest `mkdir ~/cronJobs`).

Contents of runPyAfterDate.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
after=$(date -d 20180315 +%s); # 1521052200
curr=$(date +%s);  # currently 1521100701 
if [ $curr -gt $after  ]; then 
    python path/to/script.py; 
fi;
```

Don't forget to make it an executable:

```
sudo chmod +x runPyAfterDate.sh
```

In crontab you should put the following line:

```
@daily ~/cronJobs/runPyAfterDate.sh
```

Ref link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84381/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-a-shell